# Using copy-webpack-plugin returns an error

Tags: webpack

I am trying to copy an asset folder from src to dist and I cant get this to work. In my webpack config I have:

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const images = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { 
          from: 'src/assets/*',
          to: 'dist/assets/*'
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]
};

module.exports = [
  images
];
```

but it gives me this error:

```
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'
```

I have `"copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",` and `"webpack": "^5.47.0", "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"` in my package file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default webpack configuration makes some assumptions about the environment it is executed in. If nothing else is configured, it makes several attempts to find an entry (starting) point for the build process. Among others, it looks for a file named `index.js` in the `src` folder. The file itself can be empty. So you should simply create this empty file in `src`, and the error will disappear.

Additionally, the `CopyPlugin` should be configured like this:

```
patterns: [
        {
          from: "src/assets/",
          to: "assets/",
        },
      ]
```

There are no asterisks (`*`) needed, and by default the folder `assets` will be created in `dist`.

As a (in this case unwanted) result of the build process, an empty `main.js` file will be produced in the `dist` folder. If this is not acceptable, it can be removed using the `WebpackShellPluginNext` plugin (needs to be installed and added to `package.json`), which simply deletes `main.js` at the end of the process.

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const fs = require("fs");
const WebpackShellPluginNext = require("webpack-shell-plugin-next");

const images = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "src/assets/",
          to: "assets/",
        },
      ],
    }),
    new WebpackShellPluginNext({
      onBuildEnd: {
        scripts: [
          () => {
            fs.unlinkSync("dist/main.js");
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = [images];
```

Comment: Thank you, I now get an empty file main.js in dist folder, should I change something in webpack?

Comment: @RainMan, I updated my answer to address that issue.

Comment: thanks, this really helped me, webpack config sucks :P

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/575), you are likely using a version of Webpack that `copy-webpack-plugin` doesn't support.

> ... you need webpack@5 for latest version.

Assuming you are on Webpack 4, you have two options:

1. Upgrade to `webpack@5.x`, which `copy-webpack-plugin@8.x` supports.
2. Downgrade to `copy-webpack-plugin@6.x`, which is the last version that supports `webpack@4.x`.

Comment: thanks, I downgraded the package to `6` but now I get a new error `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'` - and the folder is not copied configuring this is so hard :(

Comment: do you know if there is any reason why it gives me the new src error?